# Swagger UI showing response body {} and status 0

Tags: swagger-ui

I am using swagger to create API docs.

My issue is that once we send a call to the API, the browser sends an OPTIONS call and it returns "OK"; after that the browser sends the actual call of API and then I am not receiving the expected output.
Instead of it, it's showing no-content in response and 0 as the response code.

Please can any one help.